# Maximum principle at the border

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $Ω⊂⊂R^{2}$ a bounded regular domain and $u: \overline{Ω} → R$ a function such that $det(∇^{2}u)≤0$ in $Ω$.
I'm trying to proof that you have reached your maximum and minimum in $∂Ω$.
In my opinion, the Osserman Theorem for convex envelope can be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I edited this answer due to my counterexample being wrong. I will go over this question again in the coming days.
This looks like a version of the the maximum principle for subharmonic (or super, respectively) functions. It shouldn't work for both minimum and maximum, unless you have $\Delta u=0$.
If you are looking for a proof, you should study sub/superharmonic functions. As for this problem, it might be sufficient to note that 
$$
det(\nabla^2u)=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \leq 0
$$
where $\lambda_i$ denotes the eigenvalues of the hessian. This gives you that either one of the 2 eigenvalues is zero or they have different signs. Using the second derivate test will give you an answer in the second case. As for the case $det(\nabla^2u)=0$, you can not get any information at all. I suspect that you can apply a maximum principle here after re-writing the eqation.
In the comin days, I will look at this question again, sorry for the mistake earlier.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will remove the minus sign. My point should still be valid that it does not hold for both min and max. I might have to edit the example though.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect the "right" hypothesis is that $\det \nabla^2 u \lt 0$.  Then at any interior critical point, there would be one direction in which the second derivative is positive and another in which it is negative, so convex up and concave down respectively.  Hence an interior stationary point would neither be a maximum nor a minimum.

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain it in the second part of my answer. The 2 different signs of the eigenvalues is just a different way of saying "concave in 1 direction, convex in the other.  I used the term "second derivative test", because that is how it is called on wikipedia, since it is easier to look up.

Comment: Rereading the problem, it asks that we show the maximum and minimum are attained on the boundary.  This is subtly different than showing they *are not* attained in the interior.  So for example $u=-x_1^2$ on the unit ball, while the maximum $u=0$ is attained in the interior, it is also attained on the boundary at $(0,1)\in \partial B_1(0,0)$.

Comment: In your answer consider the point $(0,1)$. It is in $\partial \Omega$ and it is also a maximum. So you can reach the maximum in many points but the result here is true, one of this points should be in $\partial \Omega$.